# Use Perl to extract information from HTML page

Tags: html, perl, parsing

Working on testing web-based applications. The web-based application is introduced with new buttons, new tabs and etc regularly.

It will be nice to build an automated tool that read a HTML page and extract information from it, I am thinking of:

- Which buttons are there
- Where will pushing a button lead me to
- Which tabs are there
- and etc

May I ask if anyone has anything experience using Perl for a similar task?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do any automated simulation of web browsing, [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize) should be your first port of call. From the synopsis for WWW::Mechanize:

> [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize) or Mech for short, is a Perl module for stateful programmatic web browsing, used for automating interaction with websites.
>
> Features include:
>
> - All HTTP methods
> - High-level hyperlink and HTML form support, without having to parse
>     HTML yourself
> - SSL support
> - Automatic cookies
> - Custom HTTP headers
> - Automatic handling of redirections
> - Proxies
> - HTTP authentication

There are a whole set of methods for handling links--e.g. [`follow_link`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize#mech-follow_link), [`find_link`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize#mech-find_link)--and for finding inputs--e.g. [`find_all_inputs`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize#mech-find_all_inputs-...-criteria)--and you can simulate form-filling and other typical browsing activities.

There are also a number of modules for DOM parsing and manipulation--e.g. [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) and [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML).

In short, there should be plenty of perl modules out there to do what you want to do, so writing your own framework won't be necessary.